# Cross-Datacenter Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

We operate a relatively low throughput Kafka cluster with brokers in 2 data centers. Replication factor set to guarantee both data centers host a full set of data.

The data centers have high speed interconnect with low latency.  This configuration lets us operate our application hot/hot.  It has been running this way for approx 8 months.

The cluster appears to be running fine (no data loss) however there are frequent ERRORs in the kafka broker logs (below).  Any suggestions?

- FollowerRequestProcessor: Unexpected exception causing error
- StateChangeFailedException: encountered error while electing leader
  for partition [alert20,4] due to: Preferred replica 34 for partition
  [alert20,4[ is either not alive or not in the isr.  Current leader
  and ISR: [{"leader":32,"leader_epoch":49,"isr":[32]}]
- LearnerHandler:Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still
  open.
- NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for
  that topic-partition

Comment: You probably want to put in full stack traces from those errors and specify a version. Also not sure but you might want to ask this in the mailing list instead. Anyway those errors usually indicate a broker went down so it'd be good to check if all brokers are considered to be alive by the controller and in zookeeper. In a stretched cluster, a network partition seems more likely.

Comment: How do plan to keep zookeeper up when one of the data centers (or the network between them) goes down? Half a zk ensemble is not a quorum.

Comment: In the event of a data center failure we change to zk config to only contain the nodes in the surviving data center.  I suppose ideal configuration would be 3 data centers in the cluster so that a data center failure would still preserve the quorum.  I'll see if I can pull stack traces.  We are running Kafka version 0.9.0.1